# Combining several screenshot snippets into one document

Tags: editing, documents

I have a document containing several hundred entries. It looks very similar to this:

[image]

I have captured a number of entries from this document using a screenshot snipping tool. Each snipped picture is taken manually and has one or more entries from the original document. The snipped pics look like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

Now I want to make one single document using hundreds of these snippet pics which has all the entries formatted similar to the original document. It should look something like this:

[image]

I have tried ImageMagick convert program but it creates one page per snippet. I have also checked the word processing software but it doesn't allow inserting several images at once.

I am using one distro or another of Linux on all my machines. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

ScreenCaptor from Donation Coder (https://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/) puts all your screenshots automatically into a folder that you can specify.

MS Word allows you to insert multiple images in one step.

Alternatively, you could use a clipboard manager such as ArsClip (http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/97/) to copy the text portions you need.  Then you can dump all the text snippets into one file.

If those ideas are not helpful, please clarify your needs.

Comment: I don't have Windows and I have already taken the snippets.